# Why so many restransmissions on Nmap?

Tags: nmap

I executed the following code:

```
sudo nmap -sT -Pn  --max-parallelism 1 --max-retries 0 -p5481,10212,19999,2308,102 192.168.0.19 192.168.0.20
```

And when I analyzed the scan on Wireshark, I saw this:

[image: Wireshark log.]

I don't understand why Nmap do two restransmission for each port. In addition, I use `--max-retries 0`, so it should not send so many retransmissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a TCP-Connect scan (-sT).

When doing this, nmap just uses the Operating System call for `connect()`, so it's really the OS deciding wether or not a TCP Retransmission should take place or not, nmap doesn't control this in a TCP Connect Scan as far as I know. 
(The docs are missing this information)

TCP Connect can be run as a normal user, whereas the actual manipulation to put `max-retries` into effect would require a `RAW_SOCKET` (which needs root permission).

Try doing the same with a TCP SYN scan (-sS), and your `--max-retries 0` should show it's use in Wireshark!

Comment: When I execute this command I see a [TCP Out-Of-Order] for each port. How can I fix it? Besides, I want to use this command to Industrial Technologies network, so your solutions can be dangerous.

Comment: TCP out-of-order messages generally aren't an issue, so nothing to "fix" -- especially when you're running a port scan.

Comment: Separately, running any scan on an industrial network is generally dangerous. Many devices on those networks still aren't designed to be exposed to much network traffic. A connect scan will have fewer issues, but a SYN scan across five ports like you're doing should not have any problems. Of course, your mileage may vary.